# SignalR messages from server to the flash client are failed

Tags: apache-flex, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am using SignalR v2.1.2.0 and pushing messages to the client working perfectly for the clients such as android,ios and html-javascript client.

But for adobe flash client its failed. Connection created and request to the server is successfully done by this  flash client but the messages from server are blocked by some firewall especially Kerio firewall.

The same flash client successfully able to receive the incoming messages using other firewall in the network.

Is there anything I have to do or Am I missing anything ?  . Is it possible to enable SSL certificate for the SignalR website to overcome this issue ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using wamp,

Create the crossdomain.xml

**Try this code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>   
<cross-domain-policy>   
<allow-access-from domain="*" />   
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" />   
</cross-domain-policy>
```